# Справка по команде @include sсss

Tags: css, gulp, scss, sass, include

Видел в коде

```
@include font('Work Sans', 400);
```

Искал в интернете [@include sсss](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%40include%20scss&newwindow=1&sxsrf=APwXEdcg1AuTEXN-5lfAHSSnyL05L5hXTQ%3A1685335384299&source=hp&ei=WC10ZMXZD9GGxc8PyNG3mAw&iflsig=AOEireoAAAAAZHQ7aMUnD69bzv97Qdx9fs64KjCZHduX&oq=%40in&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYBTIHCCMQigUQJzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoHCCMQ6gIQJzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6BAgAEANQAFj2GGC6O2gBcAB4AIABdIgBpQOSAQMxLjOYAQCgAQGwAQo&sclient=gws-wiz), но хорошей справки по этой команде не нашел. Приведите хорошую справку по этой команде.

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin (у scss и sass мало чем отличается)